# How to detect both clicklistner and guesture using AdapterViewFlipper

Tags: android

- I have an AdapterViewFlipper where I need to listen to right and left swipes to change current item, and a clickListner to know which item user choose.
- So far using **CustomGestureDetector** I'm able to detect swipes and change accordingly. **onSingleTapUp()** however doesn't give me the item position of the click.
- If I write **OnCLickListner** inside my adapter class, guestureDetector wont work. How can I achieve both swipe listner and clickListner(to know which item from the array was chosen).

**My activity class :**

```
 package com.example.adapterviewflipper;

    import android.support.v7.app.AppCompatActivity;
    import android.os.Bundle;
    import android.util.Log;
    import android.view.GestureDetector;
    import android.view.MotionEvent;
    import android.view.View;
    import android.widget.AdapterViewFlipper;

    public class MainActivity extends AppCompatActivity {

        AdapterViewFlipper viewFlipper;
        TrendingViewPagerAdapter adapter;
        private GestureDetector mGestureDetector;
        int[] moviePosters = {R.drawable.bladerunner2049,R.drawable.beauty,R.drawable.rush,R.drawable.martian};

        @Override
        protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
            super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
            setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);
            viewFlipper = findViewById(R.id.adapterviewflipper);

            CustomGestureDetector customGestureDetector = new CustomGestureDetector();
            mGestureDetector = new GestureDetector(this, customGestureDetector);

            adapter = new TrendingViewPagerAdapter(MainActivity.this,moviePosters);
            viewFlipper.setAdapter(adapter);
            viewFlipper.setFlipInterval(6500);
            viewFlipper.startFlipping();

     viewFlipper.setOnItemClickListener(new AdapterView.OnItemClickListener() {
                @Override
                public void onItemClick(AdapterView<?> parent, View view, int position, long id) {

                    Log.v("AdapterSetOnItemClick"," "+position);
                }
            });

            viewFlipper.setOnTouchListener(new View.OnTouchListener() {
                @Override
                public boolean onTouch(View v, MotionEvent event) {
                    mGestureDetector.onTouchEvent(event);
                    return true;
                }
            });

        }





        class CustomGestureDetector extends GestureDetector.SimpleOnGestureListener {
            @Override
            public boolean onFling(MotionEvent e1, MotionEvent e2, float velocityX, float velocityY) {

                // Swipe left (next)
                if (e1.getX() > e2.getX()) {
                    viewFlipper.stopFlipping();
                    viewFlipper.showNext();
                    viewFlipper.startFlipping();
                }

                // Swipe right (previous)
                if (e1.getX() < e2.getX()) {
                    viewFlipper.stopFlipping();
                    viewFlipper.showPrevious();
                    viewFlipper.startFlipping();
                }

                return super.onFling(e1, e2, velocityX, velocityY);
            }

            @Override
            public boolean onSingleTapUp(MotionEvent e) {

                Log.v("AdapterSingleTap",e.toString());
                return super.onSingleTapUp(e);
            }
        }

    }
```

**My adapter class :**

```
package com.example.adapterviewflipper;

import android.content.Context;
import android.view.LayoutInflater;
import android.view.View;
import android.view.ViewGroup;
import android.widget.BaseAdapter;
import android.widget.ImageView;
import android.widget.Toast;

public class TrendingViewPagerAdapter extends BaseAdapter {

    Context context;
    int[] moviePosters;
    LayoutInflater layoutInflater;

    public TrendingViewPagerAdapter(Context context, int[] moviePosters) {
        this.context = context;
        this.moviePosters = moviePosters;
        this.layoutInflater = (LayoutInflater) context.getSystemService(Context.LAYOUT_INFLATER_SERVICE);
    }


    @Override
    public int getCount() {
        return moviePosters.length;
    }

    @Override
    public Object getItem(int position) {
        return null;
    }

    @Override
    public long getItemId(int position) {
        return 0;
    }

    @Override
    public View getView(final int position, View convertView, ViewGroup parent) {
        View itemView = layoutInflater.inflate(R.layout.viewflipper_row, parent, false);

        ImageView imageView = itemView.findViewById(R.id.trendingposter_imageview);

        imageView.setImageDrawable(context.getDrawable(moviePosters[position]));

        /*imageView.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onClick(View v) {

                Toast.makeText(context,"You clicked "+position,Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();

            }
        });*/

        return itemView;
    }
}
```

Thanks in advance.

Comment: where's the clicklistener for your list

Comment: edited. Please check. Since it didn't give me any results i removed it. Be it the setOnItemClickListener or the clickListern on the imageView inside Adapter class, it doesnt give me what I'm lookig for.

Answer (score 1):

You must add swip tp the imageView not flipper it self as it imageview is the view get touched, not flipper

1. create Interface as follows,

   ```
   public interface ISwip {
       public void onSwip(MotionEvent event,int position);
   }
   ```
2. Implement this in MainActivity

   ```
   public class MainActivity extends AppCompatActivity implements ISwip
   ```
3. initiate Adapter with ISwip

   ```
   public class TrendingViewPagerAdapter extends BaseAdapter {
   ISwip iSwip;

   public TrendingViewPagerAdapter(Context context, int[] moviePosters, ISwip iSwip) {
      this.iSwip = iSwip;
   }
   ```
4. set mGestureDetector to the imageView in the adapter instead of viewFlipper as follows,

   ```
           imageView.setOnTouchListener(new View.OnTouchListener() {
           @Override
           public boolean onTouch(View v, MotionEvent event) {
               //set interface here and send event back to MainActivity
               iSwip.onSwip(event,position)
               return true;
           }
       });
   ```
5. delete flipper ontouch from MainActivity

   ```
           viewFlipper.setOnTouchListener(new View.OnTouchListener() {
       });
   ```
6. implement onSwip in MainActivity

   ```
   @Override
   public void onSwip(MotionEvent event, int position) {

       itemClicked = position;
       mGestureDetector.onTouchEvent(event);
   }
   ```

**Edit** : Add position as second variable in interface method, in MainActivity then use it inside **OnSingleTapUp()** method like this :

```
class CustomGestureDetector extends GestureDetector.SimpleOnGestureListener {
        @Override
        public boolean onFling(MotionEvent e1, MotionEvent e2, float velocityX, float velocityY) {

            // Swipe left (next)
            if (e1.getX() > e2.getX()) {
                viewFlipper.stopFlipping();
                viewFlipper.showNext();
                viewFlipper.startFlipping();
            }

            // Swipe right (previous)
            if (e1.getX() < e2.getX()) {
                viewFlipper.stopFlipping();
                viewFlipper.showPrevious();
                viewFlipper.startFlipping();
            }

            return super.onFling(e1, e2, velocityX, velocityY);
        }

        @Override
        public boolean onSingleTapUp(MotionEvent e) {

            Toast.makeText(MainActivity.this,"item Selected "+clickedPosition,Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
            return super.onSingleTapUp(e);
        }
```

This worked for me.

}

Comment: How do you detect the click in this ?! Lets say I swiped up-to 3rd item and then clicked 3rd one. I would like to get its position.

Comment: click goes with  viewFlipper.setOnItemClickListener, swap done by above method

Comment: have you tested it ? Because for me that click on viewFlipper doesn't seem to work

Comment: pass AdapterViewFlipper onItemClick into the adapter and try

Comment: I'm sorry I didn't get you !.

Comment: I am asking you to write OnCLickListner inside your adapter class, then try above code sample

Comment: I added another variable "position" to your interface method and achieved what i wanted. I have edited your answer, once the edit is accepted I will be marking it as accepted answer. Thank you.

Comment: like i said answer is incomplete. If you edit it with the changes i can accept.